# How to design an election poll database

Tags: database, relational-database

I want to design an election database for my country but I use USA as an example in this question, and assume that there are 30 political parties in USA.

There are 30 parties. There are 50 states and 10 cities in each state in average(some states have 15 some has 4 etc..). I need to show each party's ratio for each state and city also countrywide.

These are my thoughts on the design:

*There is a separate table for each party(there will be 30 tables) and there are 2 columns (state and city). So every vote inserted into the relevant party's table with a state and city information so I can query election results for countrywide or for states/cities. But I have to insert every vote as a row.. As I always need number of total votes for each city, inserting every vote as a row seems like an overkill.

*There is a separate table for each party_city so queries will be fast (e.g. table names: democrats_seattle, democrats_newyork etc...). But that makes 50x10 = 500 tables!!

*There is one table for each party and it has just 3 columns 'state', 'city' and 'total_votes'. I will insert 50(states) * 10(cities)=500 row in each table. And when an user sends a vote only 'total_votes' will increment in the relevant party->state->city row.
E.g.

```
---------------------------------------
|Democrats Table                      |
|-------------------------------------|
|State         City       total_votes |
|-------------------------------------|
|Washington    Seattle    150000      |
|Washington    Medina     100         |
|....          ....                   |
|Wyoming       Cheyenne   50000       |
|Wyoming       Burlington 10000       |
---------------------------------------


--------------------------------------
|Republicans Table                    |
|-------------------------------------|
|State         City       total_votes |
|-------------------------------------|
|Washington    Seattle    50000       |
|Washington    Medina     200000      |
|....          ....                   |
|Wyoming       Cheyenne   50000       |
|Wyoming       Burlington 10000       |
---------------------------------------


 --------------------------------------
|Foo Party Table                      |
|-------------------------------------|
|State         City       total_votes |
|-------------------------------------|
|Washington    Seattle    150000      |
|Washington    Medina     100         |
|....          ....                   |
|Wyoming       Cheyenne   50000       |
|Wyoming       Burlington 10000       |
---------------------------------------
```

*Is using a NoSQL database more suitible for this app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just one table?

- Votes table, with Party, State, City and TotalVotes

This will have about 15,000 rows but that's perfectly manageable for any modern database platform.

However, you ought to '[normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)' the design, so you would end up with four tables;

- Party table, with PartyId and PartyName
- State table, with StateId and StateName
- City table, with CityId, CityName and StateId
- Votes table, with PartyId, CityId and TotalVotes

Now only the IDs are in the main table and it is much smaller. The SQL to join them back together is very simple;

```
SELECT
    p.PartyName,
    s.StateName,
    c.CityName,
    v.TotalVotes
FROM
    Votes v
        INNER JOIN Party p ON p.PartyId = v.PartyId
        INNER JOIN City c ON c.CityId = v.CityId
            INNER JOIN State s ON s.StateId = c.StateId
```